# Possible for current_page? to take two arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do the following but it doesn't work:

```
class="<%= current_page?(projects_path || new_project_path) ? 'current' : '' %>"
```

Rails doesn't error out, it just simply ignores what's to the right of the `OR` operator.

**Is it possible to give `current_page?` several optional URLs?**

[The docs doesn't give me an answer.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F)

---

Comment: "a" || "b" will always return the first string . so now you are getting what you are passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `projects_path || new_project_path` will always return `projects_path` if `projects_path` is not nil.

As both `projects_path` and `new_project_path` path are always going to be defined, you'll always get `projects_path` passed into `current_page?` method when you do:

```
current_page?(projects_path || new_project_path)
```

Update your code to:

```
class="<%= (current_page?(projects_path) || current_page?(new_project_path)) ? 'current' : '' %>"
```

Examples:

```
> 'test' || nil
=> "test" 
> nil || 'test'
=> "test" 
> 'test' || 'test2'
=> "test"
```